# roslaunch ros2 equivalent to 'rosparam command="load"'

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the ros2 equivalent to '<rosparam cmd="load" ../>'?

Looks like there are three possible cases:

- loading parameters in the root of the parameter server
- loading parameters privately into a node
- loading parameters in a "group namespace"

For example, how would you translate the following ROS1 roslaunch file that contains these three cases?

```
<launch>
   <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mypackage)/config/config.yaml" />

   <node pkg="mypackage" name="mynode" type="mynode">
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mypackage)/config/node_config.yaml" />
   </node>

  <group ns="myns"/>
        <rosparam command="load" file="$(find mypackage)/config/node_config.yaml" />
  </group>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362539/roslaunch-ros2-equivalent-to-%27rosparam-command=%22load%22%27/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2020-09-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
<param from="$(find-pkg-share mypackage)/path/to/params.yaml" />
```

[See the migration guide for launch](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Launch-files-migration-guide/#rosparam)

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2020-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2020-10-07**:
It is weird. You are right about the migration guide. But I am still getting a python launch error. This is my example:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="mypkg" exec="mynode" name="mypkg">
    <param from="$(find mypkg)/config/mynode_config.yaml"/>
</node>    
</launch>
```

It is interesting, if I use the rosparam xml tag (instead of param) it does not fail (no matter if I use the attribute "from" or "file"), but parameter values do not seem to load.
I also double checked that there the configuration file is in `install/share/mypkg/config/mynode_config.yaml`.

So by the moment I don't know what it is happening.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2020-10-07**:
I think in many scenarios "unknown" tags like  are silently ignored; hence parameter values not loading.

Can you share the Python error that you see? Note, the `find` substitution has been replaced by `find-pkg-share`, I guess that is responsible for the error.